# debugging segmentation fault using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault

When debugging my c program I get this error message

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff77f6700 (LWP 14945)]
__strcpy_sse2_unaligned ()
at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:532
532 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type.
```

I think that it's "useless" to post my code because it doesn't precise the error line.

But I know I think it cames from this function:

```
void add_user(tlistU *lu, user * u,tuser *new)
{

      tuser *nouveau = malloc(sizeof(tuser));

      u =malloc(sizeof(*u));        
      if (lu == NULL || nouveau == NULL)
      {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   strcpy(nouveau->users->nickname,u->nickname);
   nouveau->next=lu->first;
   lu->first=nouveau;
}
```

( nickname is a 9 char string )

Comment: `nouveau->users` is not allocated and not set. `user *u` and malloc(siezof(*u)) are not coherent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a little strange.  The cause of the crash is probably this, however:

```
strcpy(nouveau->users->nickname,u->nickname);
```

Note that `nouveau` is a block of *uninitialised memory* that you just requested.  You are then accessing `nouveau->users->nickname`, which assumes that `nouveau->users` is a valid pointer.

The other thing that's happening is overwriting `u` here:

```
u = malloc(sizeof(*u));
```

I suspect that what you *actually* meant to do was something like this:

```
nouveau->users = malloc(sizeof(*u));
```

That would solve both issues.

Comment: and should I write tuser *nouveau = NULL or don't initialise ?

Comment: Neither... `nouveau` still must be allocated.